# theme_fivethirtyeight() doesn't change the colors in bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

Why in the following code, colors don't change as in fivethirtyeight theme?

```
ggplot(df.long, aes(ROIs, Mean, fill=Methods))+  
geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge", width=0.75)+
  theme_fivethirtyeight()+
  scale_color_fivethirtyeight()+
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=20,hjust=1,vjust=1, face="bold", size=9), 
      axis.text =element_text(face="bold"),
      axis.title= element_text(face="bold"),
      legend.position=c(1,1),
      legend.justification = c(1, 1))
```

Comment: @baptiste, post as answer?

Comment: @BenBolker well, the text says one thing, the code another, so i'm not sure which to answer. Also the thing I hinted at is definitely a dupe.

Comment: So perhaps we could have some clarification from the OP.  If your suggestion solves her problem, we could close this as a duplicate ...

Comment: where should I add this? fill != colour

Comment: did you mean this? it didn't wotk http://pastebin.com/A2ygdPqw

Comment: ``ggplot(df.long, aes(ROIs, `Mean L2 Norm Error`, color=Methods))``

Answer (score 0):

What about using `scale_fill_fivethirtyeight()` instead of `scale_color_fivethirtyeight()`?

```
mtcars$am <- as.factor(mtcars$am)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg, fill=am))+  
        geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge", width=0.75)+
        theme_fivethirtyeight()+
        theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=20,hjust=1,vjust=1, face="bold", size=9), 
              axis.text =element_text(face="bold"),
              axis.title= element_text(face="bold"),
              legend.position=c(1,1),
              legend.justification = c(1, 1)) +
        scale_fill_fivethirtyeight()
```